# Ошибка компоновщика 2001/1120 при создании класса в C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Имеется класс Point, определенный в заголовочном файле Header.h, все методы, конструкторы, деструкторы описаны там.

При попытке собрать проект все время выбивает ошибку LNK2001 и LNK1120, подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема.

Header.h:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
static int _freeID;
const int _pointID;
double _x;
double _y;

public:

Point(const double &x = 0, const double &y = 0):
    _x(x), _y(y), _pointID(++_freeID){
}

Point(const Point& u) :
    _x(u.x()), _y(u.y()), _pointID(++_freeID) {}
~Point(void) {
    return;
}

Point& operator=(const Point &u) {
    _x = u.x();
    _y = u.y();
    return *this;
}

double& x(void) {
    return _x;
}
double& y(void) {
    return _y;
}
const double& x()const {
    return _x;
}
const double& y()const {
    return _y;
}
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& u) {
os << '(' << u.x() << ', ' << u.y() << ')';
return os;
}
const Point operator+(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
return Point(a.x() + b.x(), a.y() + b.y());
}
 Point& operator+=(Point&, const Point&);
const bool operator==(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
if (a.x() == b.x() && a.y() == b.y())
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
const bool operator!=(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
if (a.x() == b.x() && a.y() == b.y())
    return false;
else
    return true;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
Point a(1, 2);
cout << a;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предполагаю проблема в следующем.
У вас имеется [статическое поле класса](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) (`static int _freeID`), которое нигде не определено(только объявлено). Вы должны ее явно определить вне класса. Добавьте после определения класса строку

```
int Point::_freeID;
```

В этом случае, поле будет проинициализировано значением по-умолчанию, т.е. 0. Вы можете явно указать инициализирующее значение переменной

```
int Point::_freeID = 1;
```

Проблема линковки должна исчезнуть.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score -1):

Объявите ваш класс в header.h, а код определите в header.cpp

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?